# Need help defining a simple neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am very new to this and I have several question. I have code snippets of a neural network created python with keras. The model is used for sentiment anaylsis. A training dataset of labeled data (sentiment = 1 or 0) was used.
Now I have several questions on how to describe the neural network.

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,), activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.fit(train_x, train_y,
            batch_size=32,
            epochs=5,
            verbose=1,
            validation_split=0.1,
            shuffle=True)
```

I am not very clear on many of the following terms so don't be too hard on me.

- 1: Is there anything that makes this a typical model for sentiment anaylsis?
- 2: Is it "bag of words"? (My guess is yes, since the data was pre-processed using a tokenizer)
- 3: Is it "convolusional"?
- 4: Is it deep?
- 5: Is it dense - How dense is it?
- 6: What is the reason for the density(?)-numbers: 512, 256, 2
- 7: How many layers does it have (input and output layer included/excluded?)
- 8: Is it supervised / unsupervised?
- 9: What is the reason behind the three different activation functions 'relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax' in the used order?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I would also recommend you going through [this](https://cs231n.github.io/) blog. It would help you cement your concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Categorical Cross Entropy`, which is the loss function for this neural network, makes it usable for Sentiment Analysis. Cross Entropy loss returns probabilities for different classes. In your case, you need probabilities for two possible classes (`0` or `1`).
2. I am not sure if you are using a tokenizer since it is not apparent from the code you provided but if you are, then yes, it is a Bad of words model. A Bag of words model essentially creates a storage for the word roots you have in your text.
   From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model), if the following is your text:

> John likes to watch movies. Mary likes movies too.

then, a BoW for this text would be:

> {"John":1,"likes":2,"to":1,"watch":1,"movies":2,"Mary":1,"too":1};

3. The network architecture you are using is not [Convolutional](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv), rather it is a feedforward model, which connects all units from one layer to all the units in the next, providing a dot product of the values from the two layers.
4. There is no one accepted definition of a network being *deep*. But, as a rule of thumb, if a network has more than 2 middle layers (layers excluding the input and output layer), then it can be considered as a *deep* network.
5. In the code provided above, `Dense` reflects to the fact that all units in the first layer (512) are connected to every other unit in the next layer, i.e., a total of 512x256 connections between first layer and the second.
6. Yes, the connections between the 512 units in the first layer to the 256 units in the second layer resulting in a 512x256 dimensional matrix of parameters makes it *dense*. But the usage of `Dense` here is more from an API perspective rather than semantic. Similarly, the parameter matrix between the second and third layer would be 256x2 dimensional.
7. If you exclude the input layer (having 512 units) and output layer (having 2 possible outputs, i.e., 0/1), then your network here has one layer, with 256 units.
8. This model is supervised, since the sentiment analysis task has an output (positive or negative) associated with every input data point. You can see this output as being a *supervisor* to the network indicating it whether a data point has a positive or negative sentiment. An unsupervised task does not have an output signal associated with the data points.
9. The activation functions being used here serve the purpose of providing nonlinearity to the network's computations. In a little more detail, `sigmoid` has a nice property that its output can be interpreted as probabilities. So if the network is outputting 0.89 for a data point, then it would mean that the model evaluates that data point to be positive with a probability of 0.89 .
   The usage of sigmoid is probably for teaching purposes since ReLU activation units are favored over sigmoid/tanh because of better convergence properties and I don't see a convincing reason to use sigmoid instead of ReLU.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answeres all my questions. Thanks a lot for taking that time!